# angular directive attributes isolate scope undefined outside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have directive this directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective',['$http', function($http) {
      return {
        restrict: 'AEC',    
        replace: true,
        scope: { attr1: '=' , attr2: '=' }, 
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
...
}
}]);
```

If I put directive inner ng-repeat it works, so I have acces to value of attributes (eg. scope.attr1)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"
    <my-directive attr1="item.value1" attr2="item.value2"></my-directive>
</div>
```

but if I put directive outside ng-repeat, so I have only my-directive:

```
{{mymodel.value1}} {{mymodel.value2}}   //{{}} print correct value
<my-directive attr1="mymodel.value1" attr2="mymodel.value2"></my-directive>  //this fail
```

I can't access to attributes, so If I access eg. scope.attr1 I'm getting undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

the "item" object is only defined in the `div` with the `ngRepeat` so when you are trying to access specific items from the list "items" outside of the `div` with `ngRepeat` you have to use `items[index].value1` syntax. Try:

```
<my-directive attr1="items[index].value1" attr2="items[index].value2"></my-directive>
```

Comment: where exactly is my model coming from? and what does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

If the values are simple types, you should use '@' instead of the two-way model binding that '=' implies.

Also how are you reading your values. Do you read them through scope.attr1 or attrs['attr1'] - since the attr collection only holds the value in the attributes, whereas the scope actually lnks to the objects

Comment: I'm accessing attributes through scope.attr1.

Answer (score 0):

There should be nothing wrong with your code. Maybe you could spot what you're doing differently:

[Working Example Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ok4qzB1mDuAn8mtXjoIR?p=preview)

Comment: I really don't know what's wrong I have code like you posted, only I dont have ng-controller, because I have in routes mapping templateUrl<->controller. I think problem will be in expression evaluation because if I put static value into attribute like attr1="valuexyz" this value is accessible inner directive. My current solution is that I using array and ng-repeat and accessing only first item but it's ugly workaround solution.

Comment: If your data exists in an array, then I agree,the array notation is what you need. I'm glad you were able to resolve your issue.